# How can I call a function within a class?

Tags: python, function, class, oop, method-call

I have this code which calculates the distance between two coordinates. The two functions are both within the same class.

However, how do I call the function `distToPoint` in the function `isNear`?

```py
class Coordinates:
    def distToPoint(self, p):
        """
        Use pythagoras to find distance
        (a^2 = b^2 + c^2)
        """
        ...

    def isNear(self, p):
        distToPoint(self, p)
        ...
```

Answer (score 629, accepted):

Since these are member functions, call it as a member function on the instance, `self`.

```
def isNear(self, p):
    self.distToPoint(p)
    ...
```

Comment: But be careful self.foo() will use the method resolution order which might resolve to a function in a different class.

Comment: What happens if we dont use self? and directly call distToPoint(p)?

Comment: @Marlon Abeykoon the "self" argument will be missing

Comment: What if isNear and distToPoint are taking different arguments. Then How can we call distToPoint which is inside the class? Anyone can explain that for me please.

Answer (score 82):

That doesn't work because `distToPoint` is inside your class, so you need to prefix it with the classname if you want to refer to it, like this: `classname.distToPoint(self, p)`. You shouldn't do it like that, though. A better way to do it is to refer to the method directly through the class instance (which is the first argument of a class method), like so: `self.distToPoint(p)`.

Comment: @Aleski.  If it's a generic method (common to all instances and without any instance specific variables referenced in the method), could you please explain why one shouldn't use classname.distToPoint(self, p)?

Comment: @Yugmorf: There's only one situation where one should use `classname.distToPoint(self, p)`: when you're defining a subclass that overrides `distToPoint`, but needs to call the original. If you tried to call `self.distToPoint(p)` like normal in that case, you'd end up calling the method that you're just defining, and get into an infinite recursion. If not inside a class, there's also only one situation where you'd use `classname.distToPoint(obj, p)` instead of `obj.distToPoint(p)`: if obj might be an instance of the subclass, but you need to call the original `distToPoint` defined *(continued)*

Comment: in `classname` instead of the overridden version in the subclass - but note that this is very hacky and shouldn't be done in general without a *very* good reason. Note that you break subtype polymorphism when you call a method explicitly through a class (in both of the examples above, you specifically *want* to do that). So in short: you should only call a method explicitly through a class when you *need* to circumvent subtype polymorphism for some [good] reason. If the method hasn't been overridden, the two ways are equal, but `self.distToPoint(p)` is shorter and more readable, *(continued)*

Comment: so you should definitely still use it. Now, getting to the specifics of your question: if your method doesn't use any instance variables, maybe it should be a classmethod instead? You make those by adding `@classmethod` before the method, and after that you won't get an instance (`self`) as the first argument anymore - instead you get the class, so you should name the first argument eg. `cls` instead. After that, you can call the classmethod either like `obj.distToPoint(p)` or `classname.distToPoint(p)` (note the lack of `obj`). You should *still* probably use *(continued)*

Comment: `obj.distToPoint(p)`, though, if you just have a relevant instance on your hands, unless - again - you have some [good] reason to circumvent subtype polymorphism, since the classmethod could've been overridden in a subclass too, in general. Of course, if you don't have a *relevant* instance available, you should by all means call a *classmethod* directly through a class.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP, `distToPoint()` and `isNear()` are both instance methods and as such, both take a reference to an instance (usually named `self`) as its first argument. When an instance method called directly from the instance, the reference is passed implicitly, so

```py
self.distToPoint(p)
```

works.

---

If you want to call an overridden parent method from the child class, then `super()` could/should be used. In the following example, `greet()` method is defined in both `Parent` and `Child` classes and if you want to call `Parent`'s `greet()`, the prescribed way is via `super()`, i.e. `super().greet()`. It's also possible to do it via the class name, i.e. `Parent.greet(self)` but there are many arguments against such hard-coding in favor of `super()` such as flexibility, the ability to use method resolution order correctly etc.

```py
class Parent:
    def greet(self):
        print("greetings from Parent!")
        
    def parent_printer(self):
        print("this is parent printer")
        
class Child(Parent):
    def greet(self, parent=False):
        if parent:
            super().greet()                 # Parent's greet is called
        else:
            print("greetings from Child!")
        
    def printer(self, greet=True):
        if greet:
            self.greet()                    # Child's greet is called
        else:
            self.parent_printer()           # Parent's parent_printer is inherited
        
        
c = Child()
c.greet()                # greetings from Child!
c.greet(parent=True)     # greetings from Parent!
c.printer()              # greetings from Child!
c.printer(greet=False)   # this is parent printer
```