# How would I call a function within a class from the same class in python?

Tags: python, github

Given this basic example, but in reality it's more complex:
(Name of the file is TestFile)

```
class Example:
    def test1():
        print("First test")
    def test2():
        print("Second test")
    def test3():
        #Call test1()
        #Call test2()
```

I've tried `Example.test1()` and `Example.test2()`, which works, but if someone would do

```
from TestFile import Example as MagicTrick
```

Wouldn't the final function break?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class for more details please refer docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

> In reality, you would typically call self.test1() in order to call the method on an instance.

To explicitly show what @BrenBarn said:

```
class Example:
    def test1():
        print("First test")
    def test2():
        print("Second test")
    def test3(self):
        self.test1()
        self.test2()
```

Comment: Thank you as well as @BrenBarn

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't break because of that sort of import.  Using `as` to import something under a different name only affects what it's called in the place where it's imported.  In your original file `TestFile`, the class will still be called `Example` and can still refer to itself as such.  In other words, using `as` in the import just creates a "local alias"; it doesn't change any other names the imported object might have referring to it.

In reality, you would typically call `self.test1()` in order to call the method on an instance.  That won't work for your example because you didn't provide a `self` argument, but perhaps that was an oversight in your "basic" example.

Answer (score 0):

The code will work anyway because functions remember where to look for global names.

In Python every function object contains a reference to the global context in which it was defined (the attribute was renamed when passing from Python 2.x to Python 3.x):

```
# Python 2
def foo(): pass
print foo.func_globals['foo'] is foo  # --> True

# Python 3
def foo(): pass
print(foo.__globals__['foo'] is foo)  # --> True
```

This context is where the global names are looked up during the execution of the function code, no matter from where the call is coming from.

So while it's true that `Example` will not exist as a global in the context you're calling methods of `MagicTrick` from, it will defined during the execution of a method of that class (independently from the fact that you found the class using a different name and looking it up in a different context).

Answer (score -1):

I would save the call as an object and then use that inside test3

def test1():
   Print ...

def test2():
   Print ...

A= test1()

B= test2()

def test3():

A

B

Comment: That doesn't make much sense and has no apparent relation to the question.