# How to create a proper histogram in python with only one value

Tags: python, list, histogram

I wrote a function aveMean(die, numRolls, numTrials) which requires the following:

> Blockquote

- die, a Die
- numRolls, numTrials, are positive ints
- Calculates the expected mean value of the longest run of a number over numTrials runs of numRolls rolls.
- Calls makeHistogram to produce a histogram of the longest runs for all the trials. There should be 10 bins in the histogram
- Choose appropriate labels for the x and y axes.
- Returns the mean calculated

> Blockquote

Everything works fine, except:

1. the list has just one item

[image]

2. the items in the list are equal

[image]

3. or the numRolls are limited to one roll

[image]

This is how it should look like

[image]

You see that in 1.-3. there is always a little extra bar (barely visible) on the left side. How can I get rid of it? I read something about this is due to Python 3, but I didn't find out a solution.

Thanks!

P.S. I edited the code how to call the histogram and also the function that uses the call to create the histogram:

```
def getMeanAndStd(X):
    mean = sum(X)/float(len(X))
    tot = 0.0
    for x in X:
        tot += (x - mean)**2
    std = (tot/len(X))**0.5
    return mean, std

class Die(object):
    def __init__(self, valList):
        """ valList is not empty """
        self.possibleVals = valList[:]
    def roll(self):
        return random.choice(self.possibleVals)

def makeHistogram(values, numBins, xLabel, yLabel, title=None):
    pylab.hist(values, numBins)
    pylab.xlabel(xLabel)
    pylab.ylabel(yLabel)
    if(title != None): pylab.title(title)
    pylab.show()

def aveMean(die, numRolls, numTrials):
    tries = die
    testList, res = [], []
    for i in range(numTrials):
        count, tempCount, testList = 1, 1, []
        for i in range(numRolls):
            testList.append(tries.roll())
        for i in range(1, numRolls):
            if testList[i-1] == testList[i]:
                count +=1
            else:
                if count > tempCount:
                    tempCount = count
                    count = 1
                else:
                    count = 1
        res.append(tempCount)
    mean, std = getMeanAndStd(res)
    makeHistogram(res, 10, 'Quantity of Consecutive Numbers', 'Consecutive Number per Run')
    return round(mean, 3)
```

The Error Message I get is: `Unsuccessfully called makeHistogram`

Comment: Can you share the command you are using to generate your histograms?

Comment: You have not given us enough information. Just how are you getting those histograms? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Consecutive" is with a 'c', not a 'g' ;-)

Comment: Why are you even trying to make histograms for one value or one average value? A quick if statement to check for that and just display the value instead of a histogram - where a single bar for a single bin would be correct - might be a better approach.

Comment: Problem with calling the method (which was not your original question) is covered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class) - still wondering what the problem with the histograms is.

Answer (score 0):

````py
def getAverage(die, numRolls, numTrials):
    """
      - die, a Die
      - numRolls, numTrials, are positive ints
      - Calculates the expected mean value of the longest run of a number
        over numTrials runs of numRolls rolls
      - Calls makeHistogram to produce a histogram of the longest runs for all
        the trials. There should be 10 bins in the histogram
      - Choose appropriate labels for the x and y axes.
      - Returns the mean calculated
    """
    tries = die
    testList, res = [], []
    for i in range(numTrials):
        count, tempCount, testList = 1, 1, []
        for i in range(numRolls):
            testList.append(tries.roll())
        for i in range(1, numRolls):
            if testList[i-1] == testList[i]:
                count +=1
            else:
                count = 1
                if count > tempCount:
                    tempCount = count
            if count > tempCount:
                tempCount = count
        res.append(tempCount)
    mean, std = getMeanAndStd(res)
    makeHistogram(res, 10, 'Quantity of Consecutive Numbers', 'Consecutive Number per Run')
    return round(mean, 3)```
````