# Error in function in class - takes exactly 1 argument

Tags: python, class, methods

I have a class where I pass a list of documents, and in a method, it creates a list of those documents:

```
class Copy(object):
   def __init__(self, files_to_copy):
      self.files_to_copy = files_to_copy
```

Here, it creates a list of files:

```
def create_list_of_files(self):
    mylist = []
    with open(self.files_to_copy) as stream:
        for line in stream:
            mylist.append(line.strip())
    return mylist
```

Now, I try to access the method in another method in the class:

```
def copy_files(self):
    t = create_list_of_files()
    for i in t:
        print i
```

Then I run the following under `if __name__ == "__main__"`:

```
a = Copy()
a.copy_files()
```

This throws:

```
TypeError: create_list_of_files() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Am I using the method wrong?

Comment: `self.create_list_of_files()` <- `self` is the implicit first argument.

Comment: That you got this error suggests you haven't indented your code correctly (You wouldn't have been able to reference `create_list_of_files` without using self). Make sure that `create_list_of_files` is indented to the same level as `__init__`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python call function within class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method off `self`, which is the "1 argument" the method is looking for

```
t = self.create_list_of_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `create_list_of_files` as follow:
`self.create_list_of_files()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any variable to the class. In your init method, your code states that **init** takes one variable, files_to_copy. You need to pass the variable that stores the correct information. For instance:

```
class Copy(object):
   def __init__(self, files_to_copy):
       self.files_to_copy = files_to_copy

#need to pass something like this:
a = Copy(the_specific_variable)
#now, can access the methods in the class
```