# Correct my Namerror

Tags: python-3.x

what is wrong with this program.i m getting name error:

> NameError: name 'sum1' is not defined

```
 class sum:
    def sum1(self,a,b):
       self.c=a+b
       return self.c
    def init(self,a,b):
       self.a=a
       self.b=b
       return sum1(self.a,self.b)

 d=sum()
 a=6
 b=7
 h=d.init(a,b)
 print(h)
```

Comment: Use self.sum1 . sum1 is not in scope of init. But, is bound as a method on self (which is the instance itself)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python call function within class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're within a class, it has to be:

```
class sum:
    def sum1(self,a,b):
        self.c=a+b
        return self.c

   def init(self,a,b):
       self.a=a
       self.b=b
       return self.sum1(self.a,self.b)

d=sum()
a=6
b=7
h=d.init(a,b)
print(h)
```

You did not prefix the `sum1` call within the class with `self`:

```
return self.sum1(self.a,self.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on return statement.

```
return self.sum1(self.a, self.b)
```