# python merge sort within a class

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to make merge sort work within a class "Sorter for a python project, using the first code. The problem is that whenever I initialize the code, it  calls the error "merge_sort' is not defined", and if I remove the "merge_sort" and use "left = lst[:mid]", it only cuts the list into half & reorganizes, but doesn't complete the script with the whole list. Is there a way to get around this issue? Thanks!!

```
from sorter import Sorter
unsorted_list = [5, -3, 4, 10, -14, 2, 4, -5]
my_sorter = Sorter()
my_sorter.unsorted_tuple = tuple(unsorted_list)
sorted_list = my_sorter._merge_sort()
print(sorted_list)
```

My code:

```
class Sorter():

    def __init__(self):
        self.unsorted_tuple = tuple([])
        self.algorithm = 'default'

    def generate_new_tuple(self, n):

        new_list = []
        for x in range (0, n):
            new_list.append(random.randint(0, maxsize))
        tuple(new_list)
        self.unsorted_tuple = new_list
        return None

    def _merge_sort(self, reverse=False):

        lst = list(self.unsorted_tuple)
        result = []
        i,j = 0,0

        if(len(lst)<= 1): 
            return lst
        mid = int(len(lst)/2)
        left = _merge_sort(lst[:mid])
        right = _merge_sort(lst[mid:])

        while i<len(left) and j<len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
                result.append(left[i]) 
                i+=1
            else:
                result.append(right[j])
                j+=1
        result += left[i:]
        result += right[j:]
        return result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python call function within class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class)

Comment: Why do you use underscore in method name?

Answer (score 1):

You're confused about how classes and methods work.

The compiler is correct (by definition ...): there is no function `_merge_sort`.  That name applies to a method, and *must* be called with a `Sorter` object.  You have gone to a lot of trouble to set up this class, but then you've ignored those encapsulation protections when you try to recur on the halves of your list:

```
    left = _merge_sort(lst[:mid])
    right = _merge_sort(lst[mid:])
```

You're trying to invoke your method as if it were a common function.  Instead, you have to instantiate `Sorter` objects for each half of the list, set their unsorted attributes to those half-lists, and *then* you can invoke the method on each of those.  Something like:

```
left_half = Sorter()
left_half.unsorted_tuple = lst[:mid]
left = left_half._merge_sort()
right_half = Sorter()
right_half.unsorted_tuple = lst[mid:]
right = right_half._merge_sort()
```

Please consider the "weight" of this code; perhaps you can reconfigure your class to better support your needs.  For starters, give `__init__` another parameter for the initial value of the list/tuple.

Does that get you moving?