# Python calling a function from another function in a class

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn python and am having difficulty in understanding why this class throws a error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` .I have followed [How to call a function within class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class) and added `self`, but this didn't help. Here is the code, can anyone please point out the reason.

```
class Back(object):    

    def square(self,x):
        y = x * x
        return y


    def main():
        self.square(3)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I am calling it using `python square.py`

Comment: All member functions *must* take the `self` object as their first argument. It also doesn't make much sense to have the `main` function be a member function. And you never even create an instance (an object) of the `Back` class. Lastly, for something simple like this, classes and objects doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you say more about "It also doesn't make much sense to have the main function be a member function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put the `self` in the method signature of `main()`. It should look like this

```
    def main(self):
        self.square(3)
```

Without that, `self` is in fact not defined in the scope of your method, so Python complains.

EDIT: also, as `Some programmer dude` mentions, your code never creates an instance of the class just executes main. There's also a problem with your indentation (probably a copy-paste error).

Try this instead:

```
class Back(object):    
    def square(self,x):
        y = x * x
        return y

def main():
    back = Back()
    print(back.square(3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

notice how `main` is defined at the root level (it's not indented like `square`). It's not part of the class this way and doesn't need `self`. You could make it a method of the `Back` class again like this:

```
class Back(object):    
    def square(self,x):
        y = x * x
        return y

    def main(self):
        print(self.square(3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    back = Back()
    back.main()
```

Ok, this last one, it doesn't really make sens to do it this way, I admit. But I'm just trying to illustrate scope and the difference between function and methods in python (I think this logic may help the OP more, considering the question).

Comment: @tekeshi2010 I tried adding self, in that case it complains `NameError: name 'main' is not defined` at the last line `main()`

Comment: edited, I hadn't noticed some other problems with the code on the first read (txs @Some programmer dude)

Comment: can't I have main() inside the class as posted originally?

Comment: You can if you want to (I edited with an example of that). Just know that by convention, the `main` function is a *function* (meaning it is defined at the root level, not as a method under a class).