# using private method in your constructor python

Tags: python, class, oop, static-methods, python-class

I am trying to write a class that allows users to register on a platform with a username, but checks that this username does not exist in the database.

I have this code:

```py
class Freelancer:
    """Leaving this blank for now while I explore the functionality """
    number_of_sales = 0
    available_niches = ["Graphic design", "Art", "Data Analysis", "Music", "Business", "Writing and Translations"]
    usernames = []

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = _check_username(username)
    
    def _check_username(self, username):
        if self.username in Freelancer.usernames:
            print("This username already exist on our database, consider choosing another one")
        else:
            self.username = username
            Freelancer.usernames.append(self.username)
            print("You have successfully setup a username on our platform")
```

which I tested like so:

```py
David = Freelancer("dave23")
```

But I got an exception: `NameError: name '_check_username' is not defined`. What is wrong with the code? How can I call a private method from `__init__`?

Comment: Need: `self.username = self.__check_username(username)` to i.e. needs 'self.' [call methods within class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615648/python-call-function-within-class).  Need `__` (i.e. double dash) to make method private [Private Methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You missed self before calling private method.

```
def __init__(self, username):
    self.username = self._check_username(username)
```

If it is still gives error like: 'Freelancer' object has no attribute 'username'
define username variable

Comment: Need double underscores to make method private, otherwise it's still accessible by public i.e. `bill = Freelancer('bill');
bill._check_username('bill')` works [see](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/)

Comment: @DarrylG the name mangling caused by a leading double underscore is not proper "privacy". Using a single leading underscore is the standard convention, as Python lacks real functionality for `private` attributes.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `__init__` is not the constructor.
Note that `__init__(self)` already has the object (`self`), so it was already constructed before calling `__init__`. (The real constructor in Python is `__new__`).
Python does not have `private methods`, no matter how many underscores you add.

This should work:

```
def __init__(self, username):
    self.username = self.check_username(username) 

def check_username(self, username):
   ...
```

You could add the leading underscore to indicate that the method is for internal use only.

There is however another mistake in the code. It should be:

```
def _check_username(self, username):
    if self.username in self.usernames:  # <-----
        print("This username already exist on our database, consider choosing another one")

    else:            
        self.usernames.append(self.username)  # <----- 
        return username
```

You are manipulating the class. That means that if the class is instantiated again `usernames` is not empty.

Comment: "You are manipulating the class." This is **intentional**. The goal of OP's code is to remember the usernames of all instances that are created.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel right, it could be. But the code is a bit weird anyway. if `self.usernames()` was a call to a database it would make more sense.